# How can I create child windows in Performance Point Service in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I use `Performance Point Service` in `Share Point 2013` for create `BI Reports` from `SSAS`.

I need create some reports that have child window. like this picture :

[image]

Can I create a report like this.